# Metadata bug in Breeze 1.3.1? (Inheritence)

Tags: breeze

Trying out Breeze 1.3.1 and we've hit a problem. When trying to load the metadata, we get this error:

*"Error: Metadata import failed for api/securitychart/Metadata; Unable to process returned metadata:Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: Vehicle:#Project.Model.Entities"*

Just for clarification, the entity "Vehicle" is the base type from which two other entities "Motorbike" and "Car" inherit.

We've digged up a bit through Breeze's code and found that the JSON returned from the ContextProvider.Metadata() method returns the array of entityTypes in the following order:
And the error pops out when trying to parse then entity data for Motorbike.

Without having much idea what was going on, we guessed that the base class Vehicle was not available when trying to parse the metadata for Motorbike, so we manipulated the array to let it process first the base class Vehicle. After doing this, this error no longer appears, but there's a different one: *"bad navigation properties"*.

Can you guys please give us a clue about how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As of v 1.3.2, this bug should be fixed. Please post back here to either confirm that it works or that you still have an issue.

---

**Edit**: Ok, this is a bug and will be fixed in the next release. And thanks for the repro metadata, it really helped.

---

Can you send me an email with the "broken" metadata ( the json returned from the server) at breeze.ideablade.com ( with Attn: Jay Traband somewhere in the email). and I'll try to get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey, wanted to say that I'm seeing the same issue when using Breeze with an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I should be putting out a new release with this fixed either later today or early tommorow.